# Find first record that does not belong to a certain grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Three models:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :plan_category
end

class PlanCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
end
```

I have a collection of `subscriptions` and want to find the most recent one that doesn't have a `PlanCategory` "grandparent" with the `title: "unwanted"`.

This is my silly try (that is wrong in so many parts):

```
Subscription.joins(plan: :plan_category).where.not(title: "unwanted")
```

If this is not possible with common Rails methods, I'm looking for doing a loop that exits when the first fitting record is found. But again, I'm too much of a newbie to understand how I would construct such a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Subscription.joins(:plan => :plan_category).where("plan_categorys.title != 'unwanted'")
```

Comment: Excellent, please, only change the plural spelling of "category".

Comment: With help from @Gjaldon here's a Rails 4 version: `Subscription.joins(:plan => :plan_category).where.not(plan_categories: {title: "unwanted"}).last`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long version:

```
Subscription.joins(%q[
  INNER JOIN plans ON plans.id = subscriptions.plan_id
  INNER JOIN plan_categories ON plan_categories.id = plans.id
]).where.not(plans: { plan_categories: { title: "unwanted" }}).order("created_at").last
```

And here's a shorter version I haven't tested:

```
wanted_plans = Plan.joins(:plan_categories).where.not(plan_categories: { title: "unwanted" })
Subscription.joins(:plans).merge(wanted_plans).order("created_at").last
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the Rails 4 syntax. Look at my comment on the other answer for the solution I went with.